# Laravel filters system with multi checkbox

Tags: php, laravel, checkbox, filter

I am using laravel 5.4 and I want to filter search. its my front-end

[image: filter search multi checkbox option]

my code looks like this

```
class DeviceFilterController extends Controller
{
    public function filter(Feature $feature){

        $marks = isset($_POST["mark"]) ? $_POST["mark"] : null;

        $feature = $feature->newQuery();

        if(isset($marks ))
        {
            foreach ($marks as $value)
            {
                $feature->where('device_mark', $value);
            }
        }

        return $feature->get();

    }
}
```

that result just one entry

Comment: show your code on view

Answer (score 0):

You could take a different approach using `whereIn()`, assuming you `mark` input is an array of IDs like `[1, 4, 8, 22]`.

```
public function filter(Request $request) 
{
    $features = Feature::when($request->has('mark'), function($query) use ($request) {
        return $query->whereIn('device_mark', $request->mark); //Assuming you are passing an array of IDs
    })->get();

    return $features;
}
```

`when()` closure will only executes when you are sending 'mark' input. Doing it without when would look like this

```
public function filter(Request $request) 
{
    $features = [];

    if ( $request->has('mark') && $request->mark != '' ) {
        $features = Feature::whereIn('device_mark', $request->mark)->get();
    } else {
        $features = Feature::get();
    }

    return $features;
}
```